# C++ putting a 2d array of floats into a char*

Tags: c++, serialization, type-conversion

I'm trying to take a 2d vector of floats (input) and put them into a char* (output) in c++.

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::vector<float> > &input, char* &output )
{  
   char charBuf[sizeof(output)];
   int counter = 0;
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
   {
      for(unsigned int p=0; p<input.at(i).size(); p++)
      {
         //what the heck goes here
      }
   }
```

Comment: You should pass iterators to your function instead of passing a reference on a vector.

Comment: @Alerty-- why?  Is that some kind of style thing I'm not aware of?  Passing by reference doesn't do a copy, and you'd know that any iterator you got would be at the beginning of the vector.

Comment: @mmr: You can simplify your code by using iterators. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991753/refactoring-a-dumb-function-into-generic-stl-style-with-iterators-to-containers/2991797#2991797

Comment: @Alerty-- again, though, you're hoping someone calls the function with valid iterators, ie, ones that start at the beginning instead of beginning + random.  And here, you'd have to pass an array of iterators for the inner loop, so I'm not sure it's such a big savings.

Comment: @mmr: Here is an example for a 2D vector: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post316431.html#post316431

Comment: @mmr:  You do not need to pass an array of iterators! The iterator already contains a series of iterators from the vector that it contains. The STL is full of features that many people do not use because they barely use iterators. I am suggesting an alternate way. You are free to program how you want.

Comment: @Alerty-- sorry if this became a bit acerbic- that was not my intention.  You've shown me some pretty gaping holes in my knowledge, thanks for pointing them out.  As I learn more about these things, I get more daunted by the amount of code that I should probably refactor...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::stringstream` at each iteration to place the float into a `std::string` and then get the `char*` array from that. If you want one big `char*` array then just use a single string stream defined outside the loops.

Answer (score 1):

That depends greatly on what you mean by "put them into a char*".

Comment: -1 for it's not an answer. +1 for the question sorely needs clarification. So, my net action was this comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be human-readable, then you're after [`snprintf()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) -- that will convert the number 3.1415 into the string "3.1415". If you're just outputting data to be re-read by another program, then you can just dump the binary data into your output stream.

Just bear in mind that when you output the binary representation of a floating-point number, you have to be aware of how it's encoded. If you're both reading and writing on the same platform, then the encoding will be the same. In fact most desktop platforms use use the [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) spec for floating point numbers, but check up on it just to be safe.

Also, make sure that your output stream allows for some sort of versioning or other mechanism for modifying the format later on when you decide to do something different with it. Just a version number at the beginning is usually sufficient.

Comment: It seems like you may need to clarify what "just dump the binary data into your output stream" would mean-- at least, I'm not sure what it means, because he doesn't (yet) have an output stream, just a char*.

Comment: snprintf() is rather outdated ;)

Comment: @mmr: yes, the post was originally longer, but then I decided that it would do more harm than good to explain in any detail how to pursue that path, since it requires a lot more research before you can understand what you're really doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called serialization. The C++ faq has a section dedicated to this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you a `char*` view of all the `float`s in your `input` parameter.

However, I'd very careful that this is actually what you want.  The char* array is not endian robust, and I always try to avoid handing allocated pointers back to users.  Anyone using this function will need to deallocate `output` with `delete[]`, but that is in no way obvious from the function name or signature, a recipe for fragile code.

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::vector<float> > &input, char* &output )
{  
   //this was likely an error, it is always an array of size 4
   //char charBuf[sizeof(output)];

   std::vector<float> tmp_output;

   int counter = 0;  // Why was this here?

   for(unsigned int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
   {
      // This is slightly more efficient than the hand rolled loop below.
      // std::copy( input[i].begin(), input[i].end(),
      //            std::back_inserter<float>(tmp_output) );

      for(unsigned int p=0; p<input.at(i).size(); p++)
      {
         tmp_output.push_back(input.at(i).at(p));
      }
   }
   output = new char[tmp_output.size()*sizeof(float)];
   std::copy( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(*tmp_output.begin())),
              reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(*tmp_output.end())),
              output );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to put data into raw character arrays, especially when you don't know their size - which you don't here. Use a `std::string` instead, and a `std::stringstream` to write to it.

Whatever you do, get rid of that `charBuf` thing; anything you do with it will be wrong, since `sizeof(output)` is not the size of the output array.

Assuming you want a human-readable string, you might want something like

```
std::string foo(const std::vector<std::vector<float> > &input)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0) stream << "\n";
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < input[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if (j != 0) stream << ",";
            stream << input[i][j];
        }
    }

    return stream.str();
}
```